# Creating new posts on google plus page using php

Tags: php, google-plus

how can i Create a new posts on a google plus page (My own page)

ifound this
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

but it on java and python .. not php

Comment: Google+ is dead - don't waste your time! :)

Comment: ;)  i know but .. work is work

Comment: Please add a little more eforts. no code so far?  PHP is quite different from Java/Python btw. are yyou sure you need to use PHP ?

Comment: i dont think google+ ever did a api for posting? you might have to use curl to login and then to post "a new post" -- actually just see that they do..

Comment: yes i want to use PHP

Comment: @David is that possible with google .. using api ?

Comment: well if there is a api you can create functions to use it, try https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/?hl=en here hopefully you can find a wrapper class, if not look up curl, its not too bad to use but there will be issues if they change post fields, etc or post location. I dont use google + so cant really help